# Batch or Powershell rename folder to yesterday's date

Tags: powershell, date, batch-file

I am building out a batch file that takes a zip archive which is uploaded nightly and unzips the contents and puts it in a specific folder.

Currently, I am generating a temporary folder named "tmpExtract". Once the files are extracted, I want to rename "tmpExtract" with yesterday's date. Preferably in `MM-DD-YYYY` format.

I was able to locate a PowerShell command to get yesterdays date, however, I am stuck at the part where I can rename the directory to yesterdays date.

```
PowerShell $date = Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(-1); $date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

The full directory that I am using:
`Y:\\Archive\TestFolder\Recordings\tmpExtract\`

The full directory that I am looking for once the rename has completed: `Y:\\Archive\TestFolder\Recordings\06-09-2021`

I am open to either PowerShell or Batch/CMD. Whichever works best!

Comment: [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.1)?

Comment: The desired resulting foldername does not match the date pattern you describe (dd-MM-yyyy vs yyyy-MM-dd.. Also, there is no need for the two backslashes `Y:\\Archive...`

Comment: PowerShell: `Get-Item -Path 'Y:\Archive\TestFolder\Recordings\tmpExtract' | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0:dd-MM-yyyy}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1))`

Comment: …and from a batch-file, that would be `@%SystemRoot%\System32\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Get-Item -Path 'Y:\Archive\TestFolder\Recordings\tmpExtract' | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0:MM-dd-yyyy}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1))"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Theo's response I found the following code to work best

`powershell Get-Item -Path 'Y:\Archive\TestFolder\Recordings\tmpExtract' | powershell  Rename-Item -path 'Y:\Archive\TestFolder\Recordings\tmpExtract' -NewName ('{0:dd-MM-yyyy}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1))`

I needed to add `powershell` and `-Path 'Y:\Archive\TestFolder\Recordings\tmpExtract'` to the second part of the string. After testing it works as intended.

Also, I was unaware that the second '' was not needed for a mapped network path.

Comment: If you run this from PowerShell (console or ISE), you can remove the `powershell` and also the `-path` on Rename-Item as it is piped through to the Rename-Item cmdlet.